# Using php if statement to validate that the input value is between 0 and 100

Tags: php, if-statement

I tried the following to make sure the input value is between `0` and `100` but it didn't work.

```
  if (($_POST['rate']) >= '0' || =<'100') {
      $rate = $_POST['rate']
  }
  esle {
      echo '<p>Please enter a value between 0 and 100</p>';
  }
```

Comment: For future reference, *"didn't work"* is not a good description of the problem. Next time, include the exact error you are getting (or show an example of expected vs. actual output/result, depending on the type of question).

Comment: I added this to my favorites for I just realized what great material this is for a beginner's exam or discussion in class: let students try to find everything that's wrong with this one line. I couldn't have come up with a better example if I tried. (Not trying to be rude, this is really useful in its own right)

Answer (score 6):

**Issue 1: `string` vs `int`**

Currently, you are comparing strings, not numbers. Cast your `$_POST` variable to `int` and remove the apostrophes around `0` and `100` to fix this:

```
$rate = (int) $_POST['rate'];
if ($rate >= 0 || =< 100) { /* ... */ }
```

**Issue 2: something is missing**

However, this is still not going to yield the desired results as you are missing `$rate` for the second comparison. Change it to:

```
$rate = (int) $_POST['rate'];
if ($rate >= 0 || $rate =< 100) { /* ... */ }
```

**Issue 3: `or` vs `and`**

And we're still not there. Currently, you are using [`||` (*or*)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). You need to use [`&&` (*and*)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) instead:

```
$rate = (int) $_POST['rate'];
if ($rate >= 0 && $rate =< 100) { /* ... */ }
```

**Issue 4: `=<` vs `<=`**

Still not going to work. One of your [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is the wrong way round. `=<` should be `<=` instead:

```
$rate = (int) $_POST['rate'];
if ($rate >= 0 && $rate <= 100) { /* ... */ }
```

**Issue 5: user input**

`$_POST` holds data coming from a user. Never trust user data. What, for example, if there is no `rate` element? In that case, PHP will throw an error of type [`E_NOTICE`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) (which you might not even see if you don't have your reporting set to `E_ALL`) and once converted to `int`, evaluate to `0`! Hence, your test would pass, which is probably not what you want. To prevent that, use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.isset.php):

```
$rate = isset($_POST['rate']) ? (int) $_POST['rate'] : -1;
if ($rate >= 0 && $rate <= 100) { /* ... */ }
```

**Issue 6: something *esle***

As pointed out by [Pedro Lobito](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43443830/3316645), you managed to also introduce a typo: `esle` should be `else`.

**Issue 7: semicolon**

As pointed out by [Gert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43443804/3316645), your line `$rate = $_POST['rate']` is missing the `;` at the end.

**Summary**

I don't mean to be rude, but seeing how many mistakes you managed to squeeze into this simple `if`, I get the feeling that you should probably consult some basic PHP tutorials instead of Stack Overflow at this point.

Comment: nice answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Several issues with your code,

**1 -** This is a [string](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php): `'100'`, this is an [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php): `100`, you cannot check if a number is bigger than a string, or at least, it doesn't make sense.
**2 -** The correct syntax of the [comparasion operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is: `>=` **NOT** `=>`
**3 -** You've a typo in `esle`, it should be `else`

---

Based on the above, you need something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['rate']))
{
    $rate = $_POST['rate'];
    if($rate >= 0 and $rate <= 100)
    {
        echo "rate is between 0 and 100";
    }
}
```

---

**Note:**

You may want to read about `php` [Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) (`and`, `or`, etc..)

Comment: Good catch with the `esle`, I missed that! However, `empty()` is probably not a good idea, as both `"0"` as well as `0` will be considered empty - but OP wants to allow them.

Comment: @domdom, you're right, I'll change it to `isset`, tks for pointing that.

Answer (score 0):

format it like this to check between numbers

```
$temprate=$_POST['rate'];
          if(($temprate >= '0') && ($temprate <= '100')){
             //you forgot the semi colon here by the way
             $rate = $temprate;
          }
          esle{
             echo '<p>Please enter a value between 0 and 100</p>';
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

To test number is between 0 and 100, try this,

```
if($_POST['rate'] >= 0 && $_POST['rate'] <= 100)
```

Comment: what will happen if  `$_POST['rate']` isn't set ?